# Centering draggable element over element it was dropped in - jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this program that makes dynamic draggable divs, the user can then drop the a into any td in a table. When the div is dropped, I'm trying to make the dragged div be centered over the td it was dropped in.

I was wondering if there is a method or way to do this with jQuery to help with this. I tried something like this:

```
   var selectedCell; //<td></td> dynamic <div></div> was dropped on

$("td").droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) { 
     selectedCell = event.target;
      $(currentlyDragged).postion({
        selectedCell = '<td id="'selectedCell'"><center>"'+ currentlyDragged + '"</center></td>' //the dropped div should be centered over td 
      })
  }
});
```

but it didn't work, is it possible to do this with dynamic divs?

**Code Snippet:**

```js
var text;
var selectedText;
var inputBox = document.getElementById("input");

function showInputBox(){
   inputBox.style.display = "block";
}

var elementCounter = 0;
function addElement() { 
 text = document.getElementById("input").value;

  // create a new div element and give it a unique id
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.id = 'temp'+elementCounter;
  elementCounter++

  // and give it some content
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(text); 
  
  // add the text node to the newly created div
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent);  

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 

    var currentlyDragged;


  $(function() {
    
 
    $("[id^='temp']").draggable({
      drag: function (e) {
         currentlyDragged = e.target.id
         selectedText = event.target;
         text = $(selectedText).html();
    }
    });


   var selectedCell;

    $("td").droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) { 
         selectedCell = event.target;
         alert("<td id=selectedCell><center> + currentlyDragged + </center></td>");
      }
    });
  });
  document.getElementById("input").value = " ";
}

function addRedElement() { 
 text = document.getElementById("input").value;

  // create a new div element and give it a unique id
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  newDiv.id = 'temp'

  // and give it some content
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(text); 
  
  // add the text node to the newly created div
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent);  

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 

  $(function() {
    

    $("div").draggable({
     drag: function (e) {
         console.log('being dragged');
         selectedText = event.target;
         text = $(selectedText).html();
         console.log(text);
    }
    });
    $("#temp").draggable({
      drag: function (e) {
         console.log('being dragged');
         selectedText = event.target;
         text = $(selectedText).html();
         console.log(text);
    }
    });



    $("td").droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) { 
        var selectedDiv = event.target;
          $( this )
          .addClass("div")
            .html(text);
              $("div").draggable();

          $( "#temp" ).remove();
      }
    });
  });
  document.getElementById("input").value = " ";
}
```

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}

.blank {

}

.div3 {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 20px ;
  background-color: white;
  width: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}


.div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}

td{
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 20px ;
  width: 200px;
}

div:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<h1>Input text:</h1>
<p>input text and it will become a draggable div. You can then drag it to one of the tds </p>
    <input id="input" type="text" value="text">
    <button onclick="addElement()" >input</button> 

    <p>Drag your outputs to the div:</p>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td height="50" width=100 id="cell1"></td>
    <td height="50" width=100 id="cell2"></td>
    <td height="50" width=100 id="cell3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>


     <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```